# Incorporate multiple VR applications into a single webpage

Tags: three.js, aframe, webxr

I have multiple different, independent VR applications running on different servers (I have access to all of them). They also use different frameworks: babylon.js, three.js and a-frame. Now the idea is to be able to enter each application from within an other VR webpage (basically a navigation). I've loaded each of them into an iframe and I am able to switch between them.

This works fine until the VR mode for mobile devices is used as it is different from the fullscreen of desktop webpages. I wouldn't mind a short exit and reentering of the VR but I'm not able to execute the functions responsible to do this because of the missing consent of the user. It will return: `the requested session requires user activation`.

Full error:
[image: user activation required]

- Is there a way around the user activation?
- Is there any other way to switch between the vr applications?

Thanks for any help provided :D

Comment: There's absolutely no way around user activation. Browsers prefer user safety over functionality, and if the user doesn't allow to enter fullscreen, there's no way to force it.